[Hive]unpivot question
図1のようにcolumn1から4に対し、以下のような表があります。
column1:11、21、31、...n1
column2:12、22、32、...n2
column3:13、23、33、...n3
column4:14、24、34、...n4

これをcolumn4に対し、列行展開を行い、図2のようにしたいです。
どういったコードで解決できるでしょうか？列挙する以外方法はないのでしょうか？
図1

図2

sample code [Hive]
select t1.row1,t2.column1,t2.column,t2.column3 t2.column4 from table1 t1
LATERAL VIEW explode (map(
  'column4', column4
)) t2 as key, value

